# How do I navigate a website after starting a session and signing in?

Tags: python, authentication, session, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to use python to sign into a website, run some searches, and scrape the data from these searches. I feel like I am correctly signing in since I'm no longer getting an error message when running post. Every time I try to 'get' the site's search page however, I just get a random page.

`print(skurniksearchpage.url)` should print the long URL I provided, but I get a landing page instead.

Code posted below:

```
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

loginurl = 'https://www.sevenfifty.com/user/sign_in'
secureurl = 'secure_url'
payload = {'email':'me@email.com','password':'oohlala'}

#with an active session, sign in and scrape
with requests.session() as s:
    s.post(loginurl, data=payload)
    r = s.get(secureurl)
    print(r.text)
    skurniksearchpage = s.get('https://buyer.sevenfifty.com/search?page=1&per_page=10&sort=score&direction=desc&query=skurnik&previouslyOrdered=false')
    print(skurniksearchpage.url)
```

Comment: If the search is performed using asynchronous libraries like AJAX, then Python won't able to deal with that, because it's not a web browser so can't deal with Javascript. For that sort to work, it's better to use something like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/) that's designed to test websites automatically.

Comment: the search page is on a different page.

Comment: payload of auth, have other payload. and probably field `authenticity_token` is required